# C/C++ Compiler and Editor with theme

Tags: c++, c, compiler-construction, editor, themes

I would like to know if there is any C/C++ compiler and editor just like code blocks but you can change the theme and and skin and give it a dark look. I have tried using Code blocks and it was nice except the theme is too plain and it makes it boring. I tried eclipse but I was having trouble compiling using eclipse. So if you know any software that has a built in compiler with it and allows you to change themes and skin please let me know.

Comment: did you try genie editor?

Comment: try net beans, dev-c++

Answer (score 1):

[NetBeans](https://netbeans.org/) has some dark themes:

**Editor themes:**

- http://netbeansthemes.com/
- http://svenspruijt.nl/themebuilder/

**(Dark) Window themes:**

- [ez-on-da-ice](http://plugins.netbeans.org/plugin/40985/ez-on-da-ice)
- [Dark Nimbus](http://plugins.netbeans.org/plugin/46003/)
- [Sublime](http://plugins.netbeans.org/plugin/51424/sublime-theme)
- [NetBeans Dark Theme](http://plugins.netbeans.org/plugin/52624/netbeans-dark-theme)
- [Panorama Eye Friend](http://plugins.netbeans.org/plugin/51585/panorama-eye-friend-theme)
- *Install through Netbeans Plugin Center:* **Dark Look and Feel Themes** (NB 7.3+)

Comment: how do I compile my program using netbeans?

Comment: NetBeans supports C/C++, so just create a project and compile it. See here: https://netbeans.org/features/cpp/index.html

Answer (score 1):

You may try [Codelite](http://codelite.org) as C++ IDE